# cvCaptureFromFile- Opening Video from specific path - Raspberry Pi

Tags: c++, c, opencv, raspberry-pi

I have OpenCV-2.4.9 installed in Raspberry Pi. Right now I am trying to load a video from specific path and for that I tried with both C and C++ API

C API:  cvCaptureFromFile(path);

C++ API: VideoCapture cap; cap.open(path)

I am getting error and it says could not open file.

It works well in Windows and Linux, but not in Raspberry Pi. Am I missing something?

C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(){
  VideoCapture cap("C:/Users/nava/Videos/file.mp4");
  if (!cap.isOpened()){
    cout << "Error opening video stream" << endl;
    return -1;
  }
while (1){
    Mat Frame;
    if (!cap.read(Frame)){
        cout << "No Frame available" << endl;
        waitKey();
    }
    imshow("output", Frame);
    if (waitKey(33) == 27) break;
}
}
```

C Code:

```
#include "highgui.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  cvNamedWindow("video",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
  CvCapture* capture = cvCreateFileCapture("/home/pi/Desktop/test.mp4");
  IplImage* frame;
  while(1)
  {
   frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);
   if(!frame) break;
   cvShowImage("video", frame);
   char c = cvWaitKey(33);
   if(c == 27) break;
  }
  }
```

Comment: support for opencv's arcane c-api is fading rapidly, please avoid using c.

Comment: Yeah ok, but I dont understand why it fails in the C++ API case too?

Comment: that too on raspberry pi alone, but not on windows and Linux.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install UV4L driver.Follow this tutorial :

> http://www.linux-projects.org/modules/sections/index.php?op=viewarticle&artid=14

Comment: uv4l driver is already the latest version. By the way I forgot to tell that the live capture from the camera (logitech) is working, but the only problem is, I could not open a video from a specific path.