# OpenCV! How Capture videos?

Tags: c, opencv, video, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm participating in a team project, and i've a source code. That code, need OPEN CV, because we are working in image processing.

We need to capture a video and then, do some functions. That video is located in the path of project.

Happens that for capture a video we, first define a path, like:

```
char *videofile = "video-tp2.avi";
```

And then we've the capture:

```
CvCapture *capture;
capture = cvCaptureFromFile(videofile);
```

Finally we check if, we have a capture, and supossedly, if we do not have a video file, system may alert. It is precisely the other way around, the system alerts when the video exists and is within the project

```
if (!capture)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Erro ao abrir o ficheiro de vídeo!\n");
        return 1;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: If an answer solved your problem or helped you, please consider to accept it, see also:
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

**cvCapture** is a struct which the [documentations](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html) refers as a `black-box`:

> Note: In C API the black-box structure CvCapture is used instead of
>   VideoCapture.

You can try `cv.QueryFrame(capture)`. It will return **NULL** if it fails (see this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30187093/cvcapturefromfile-opening-video-from-specific-path-raspberry-pi)):

```
   IplImage* frame;
   frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);
   if(!frame) {
     // FAIL
   }
```

However you should switch to the `C++` interface because the `C` API is deprecated (see [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/46558/the-function-cvcapturefromfiletunnelavi-is-not-working-in-opencv-249/))